Cholesky factorization of a conditional multivariate normal distribution
Let $X$ be a random vector with multivariate normal distribution: $X\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\Sigma)$.
Let $L$ be the Cholesky factorization of $\Sigma$: $\Sigma = LL'$, so that we can write
$$X=L X_0 +\mu,$$
with $X_0\sim \mathcal{N}(0,I)$.
If we split $X$ in two vectors $X=(X_1,X_2)$, we know that
$$X_1|X_2\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu_{1|2},\Sigma_{1|2}),$$
with $\mu_{1|2}=\mu_1 + \Sigma_{12}\Sigma_{22}^{-1}(X_2-\mu_2)$ and $\Sigma_{1|2}=\Sigma_{11}-\Sigma_{12}\Sigma_{22}^{-1}\Sigma_{21}$,
and where $\mu=(\mu_1,\mu_2)$ and $\Sigma_{1/2,1/2}$ correspond to sub-matrix of $\Sigma$.
Is there a formula to obtain the Cholesky factorization of $\Sigma_{1|2}$, directly from $L$ or some sub-matrices of $L$?
I'm asking this because I want to simulate the conditional distribution $X_1|X_2$ from $L$, while avoiding to calculate some inverse of matrices, such as $\Sigma_{22}^{-1}$.

Even with Cholesky decomposition, you cannot completely avoid matrix inversion -- ofc inverting an upper triangular matrix is way easier.
